# Can I put this RAM into my iMac 27" mid 2010? (Corsair CMSO8GX3M2A1333C9)

Tags: upgrade, memory

I have an aluminium iMac (from mid/late 2010 I believe).

I want to upgrade the memory from 4gb to 8 or 16. I'm no hardware guy, but from the info I read it would appear I can upgrade to any SO-DIMM RAM module.

So just to check before I go ahead and buy... do you guys believe that this will go in my iMac?

http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002YUF8ZG/ref=asc_df_B002YUF8ZG6968622?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=googlecouk06-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22206&creativeASIN=B002YUF8ZG

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's memory upgrade page for your model iMac calls for PC-10600 SO-DIMMs.
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4255

Those Corsair SO-DIMMs meet all the stated specifications, even though some sites erroneously list them as PC-10666 (Corsair lists them as PC-10600).

Furthermore, if you look through the reviews on Newegg and other sites for this memory, you can see reports of people using it successfully in their Macs.

So I would conclude that yes, it's safe to use it in your 2010 iMac.

Comment: Cool, thanks. :) They seem cheap compared to other "Mac-specific" ram upgrades. Are they crap? Or is it just RAM manufacturers trying to capitalise on the Apple brand?

Comment: Here: http://www.corsair.com/cmso8gx3m2a1333c9.html it says they are 10600 (under tech specs) so I guess even more reason to think they're compatible?

Comment: Yes, a quick Google search produced some results saying they were PC-10666, but if Corsair says they are PC-10600 I would believe them. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @ThomasClayson I would guess the latter. I am also running non-Apple RAM upgrades in my machines. So far they've worked fine.

Comment: That said I just bought 2 of these myself: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231342
They are a bit cheaper and highly rated.

Comment: Ah thanks guys :) @JulioR. I can't seem to find any of those available for UK unfortunately, so I'll stick with my corsair ones.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3918?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), the Mid 2010 has four slots for 1333 MHz DDR 3 modules. Assuming that your current 4 GB are 2x2GB modules, you can install the Corsair modules for a total of 12 GB. Or you can buy four Corsair modules and throw out the 2x2GB for a total of 16 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace all 4 slots of 2 GB each with 4 slots of 4 GB each. The iMac slowed down dreadfully. So I just replaced the two rear slots furthest from the screen to have 2 front original slots of 2 GB each and 2 new slots of 4 GB each to give me a total RAM of 12 GB and my 27 inch 2010 iMac is working very well and super fast again.